# The meaning of the word "agency" in this sentence: How dare she have agency again?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC:[Indian](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-63873033)

At the age of 44, when her mother fell in love and remarried, she again attracted the "ire of society" - "How dare a widow not be the sad, weeping, pleasureless woman that she's supposed to be? **How dare she have agency again?**"

What does **"agency"** mean here? I looked up some dicitionaries but there is no clear equivalence that sit well in this sentence.

So does it mean "a mediator who arranges the marriage" or "a spouse" or "willingness to marry"?

Comment: If those three definitions are the only ones provided by your dictionary, then you're not using a very good dictionary. (I don't think that the second and third are even correct definitions.) Please do more research; decent dictionaries do, indeed, contain the right definition.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of 'agency' here is:

> **the ability to take action or to choose what action to take**
>
> *The protest gave us a sense of agency, a sense of our own power to
> make a difference.*
>
> *When the legal system acquitted these women on the grounds of insanity
> it denied their agency.*

[Agency (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agency)

You can call it 'freedom' or 'liberty' if you like. The society which expressed its 'ire' seems to be one which denies women, including widows, the power to decide what to do with their own lives, property, money, career, etc.